# Spring not loading static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7

am new to Spring Framework. I am trying to create a test application using spring.Views are running fine, but on my JSPs I am unable to use static content.
Even if i try to access them directly, they are not opening.
I have tried every solution I found online.
Please tell me if I am missing something.

This is my springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"     
xsi:schemaLocation="    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">    

<mvc:annotation-driven/>    
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/"/>    
<context:component-scan base-package="com.portal"/>    

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">    
<property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />    
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />    
</bean>    
</beans>
```

Following is my web.xml entry

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
```

I have some static files located in

```
/src/static/img/apple-touch-icon.png
/src/static/css/bootstrap.css
/src/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
/src/static/css/styles.css
/src/index.html
```

But when I type url

http://localhost:8080/springdemo/index.html

or

http://localhost:8080/springdemo/static/img/apple-touch-icon.png

It is displaying 404. :(

Also

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/springdemo/static/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

or

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://localhost:8080/springdemo/static/img/apple-touch-icon.png`">

are not working.

Please help me as I have just started learning Spring.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to put your static content in **WEB-INF** folder 
and you have mapped your resource

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/"/>
```

that means any file in "WEB-INF/resources/" are available "/". For example if you have some image in resource

```
 /WEB-INF/resources/static/image/icon.png
```

it is accessible by

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/icon.png" ....>
```